# How to reduce too much brightness on the face in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

On the following picture I am trying to reduce too brightness and lighting effect on the girl's face in Adobe Photoshop. I tried almost all options in Photoshop from top navigation > Image > Adjustment > but not able to reduced the highlights/lighting effect. Please guide or give me any tutorial that help me to do so.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming related questions. Try your question over here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Photoshop. I wanted to mark it as a migration but the photography site is not an available option for that.

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-auto-corrections-tools-in-photoshop.html

Answer (score 0):

Your image does not consist information in highlight zone. Very poor dinamic range of your camera(is this phone?). If you want edit photo for future, you will get shots in raw and looking for override higlight zone before shooting.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the step to reduce over exposure before editing is an option, however what you can do is go to the filters tab. Next, you are going to want to select liquefy. This tool can detect facial features and help you make specific changes to the face. Good luck! I actually went in and fixed it using the curves tool which is also an adjustment. Lastly I made her face matte to hide the shine.

Here's the new version: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgzZp.jpg)